# auto-py-to-exe failed to execute script du to unhandled exception

Tags: python, pyinstaller, qt-designer, auto-py-to-exe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFolY.png)hi em trying to make exe file for my project using auto-py-installer, and when i launch it , i have an exception : No such file or directory : plotting.ui. i used Qt Designer for making UI i load 'plotting.ui' on my script.

```
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QDialog,QMainWindow,QLabel,QWidget,QFrame,QPushButton,QComboBox\
    ,QHBoxLayout,QFileDialog
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import uic
from pathlib import Path
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import os
class graph_kf_data(QMainWindow) :
    def __init__(self):
        super(graph_kf_data, self).__init__()
        
        scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self.setWindowTitle("DATA ANALYSIS APPLICATION")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(scriptDir + os.path.sep +'images/'+'logo.png'))
        uic.loadUi('ploting.ui',self)

        self.comboBox = self.findChild(QComboBox,'comboBox')
        self.frame_4 = self.findChild(QFrame,'frame_4')
        self.pushButton = self.findChild(QPushButton,'pushButton')
        self.pushButton_2 = self.findChild(QPushButton,'pushButton_2')

        #create a horizantal layout
        self.horizantalLayout_7 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_4)
        self.horizantalLayout_7.setObjectName('horizantalLayout_7')

        #create canvas
        self.fugure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas =FigureCanvas(self.fugure)
        #add canvas

        self.horizantalLayout_7.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.view_graphs)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.upload)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This code is not what caused the problem, of course.  If you are loading "plotting.ui" at run-time, then you need to tell pyinstaller that you need that data file.  It can detect what Python modules you need, but it can't tell what data files you require.

Comment: so how can i fix this problem ? help me plz